# pegar números de clicks e visualizações de uma página do Facebook utilizando o Graph API

Tags: facebook, api

Como posso pegar números de clicks e visualizações de uma página do Facebook utilizando o Graph API? Caso alguém conheça outra forma aceito sugestões.

Comment: Você quer somente os dados da página ou das publicações?

Comment: da publicação, como o número de clicks e o número de visualizações.